# PHP: fill array from multiple sources

Tags: php, database, arrays

I need to create an array, in which first two columns are filled from MySQL DB, while other 1440 columns are filled with zeros. Please see my code.

First two columns are filled correctly, while zeros(0,1440) results in Array[0]. As a results the number of columns is 3 (Array[3]) instead of 1442.

What's wrong with it?

```
$query2="SELECT resID, resTitle FROM my_db.resources;";
$result2=DatabaseConnector::ExecuteQueryArray($query2); 

$i=0;
    $resAlloc = array();
    foreach ($result2 as $row):
        $resAlloc[$i] = array($row['resID'],$row['resTitle'],zeros(0,1440));
        $i++;
    endforeach;

// Generate an array of zeros
function zeros($rowCount, $colCount){
    $matrix = array();
    for ($rowIndx=0; $rowIndx<$rowCount; $rowIndx++){
        $matrix[] = array();
        for($colIndx=0; $colIndx<$colCount; $colIndx++){
            $matrix[$rowIndx][$colIndx]=0;
        }
        var_dump(memory_get_usage());
    }
    return $matrix;
}
```

Comment: 1440 columns? umm... ouch? And how is this **NOT** working? We're not going to guess for you.

Comment: First two columns are filled, while zeros(0,1440) results in Array[0]. As a results the number of columns is 3 (Array[3]) instead of 1442.

Comment: When you have **1440** columns, ***all*** filled with zeroes, you know it's time to restructure your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$query2="SELECT resID, resTitle FROM my_db.resources;";
$result2=DatabaseConnector::ExecuteQueryArray($query2); 

$i=0;
$resAlloc = array();
foreach ($result2 as $row):
    $resAlloc[$i][] = $row['resID'];
    $resAlloc[$i][] = $row['resTitle']
    for ($j=0; $j<1440; $j++)
    {
        $resAlloc[$i][] = 0;
    }
    $i++;
endforeach;
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Given your comment above,

```
    $resAlloc[$i] = array($row['resID'],$row['resTitle'],zeros(0,1440));
```

will never work. What you're creating is an array that has 3 elements. This code is the equivalent of:

```
   $resAlloc[$i] = array(
      0 => $row['resID'],
      1 => $row['resTitle'],
      2 => array(...)   // array returned from the zeros() function
   );
```

It won't be a 1440 element array, it'll be a 3 element array.

For this code to work as you'd like, you'll have to do something more like:

```
$resAlloc[$i] = array(0 => $row['resID'], 1 => $row['resTitle']);
for($j = 2; $j < 1442; $j++) {
   $resAlloc[$i][$j] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not create the columns with all 0's, then put data in the first two? This code doesn't require rolling your own function to generate an array of zeros, it uses the built-in function to do the work.

```
$resAlloc[$i] = array_fill(0,1442,0);
$resAlloc[$i][0] = $row['resID'];
$resAlloc[$i][1] = $row['resTitle'];
```